# python numba numpy array from external library

Tags: arrays, numpy, types, numba

I have an array from a FEniCS function object (e.g. named xval) usually accessed by `np.array(xval.vector())`. Using numba as follows (other values except tbl are `float` or `int`):

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def updateMatdataGen(xval,tbl,minTbl,maxTbl,scaler):
    npXval = np.array(xval.vector(),dtype=np.float32)
    xclp = np.clip((npXval-minTbl)/(maxTbl-minTbl)*scaler,0,scaler).astype(int)
    return tbl[xclp]
```

results in `non-precise type pyobject`. The xval comes from a C++ library and is easily exchanged with numpy. The error is already in line `npXval = np.array(xval.vector(),dtype=np.float32)`.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried converting `xval` to a numpy array *outside* of the numba function?  I've run into this issue a couple times with other libraries and I always end up making sure my numba functions don't handle any of the interop.

Comment: Hmmm ... good hint. Next error is that np.clip ist not supported. Changing to np.min/np.max results in: "No implementation of function Function(<function amin at 0x7fdb0627a040>) found for signature: >>> amin(array(float64, 1d, C), float64)" ... ok clip cannot be raplaced by min/max ...

Comment: The xclp calculation is the time consuming part. So I took it out of the function (no jit needed anymore) but since I called the function 3 times now I do it only one times and then call the function, which is also much faster ;-)

Comment: `np.clip` isn't supported by numba, but it's pretty easy to implement yourself.  That should be faster than pulling it outside the function.